# How do I click on a link in the same row as another string which I've made into a list?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to click on a link in the same row as another link/text which I have copied into a list. What is the best way to go about this?

I want to click on the "Edit" Button in the same row as the Invoice. I copied all the Invoices into a list but I had to remove the "invoice #" part out of each invoice.

Thank you for your help!

```html
<table id="div__bodytab" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="">
<tbody><tr class="printonly"><td height="0" id="div__labprintcol1" nowrap="" class="listheadertdleft listheadertextb uir-list-header-td uir-list-header-align-ctr"><div class="listheader">Edit | View</div></td><td height="0" id="div__labprintcol2" nowrap="" class="listheadertd listheadertextb uir-list-header-td uir-list-header-align-rt"><div class="listheader">ID<span class="listheadersort"></span></div></td><td height="0" id="div__labprintcol3" nowrap="" class="listheadertd listheadertextb uir-list-header-td"><div class="listheader">ID2<span class="listheadersort"></span></div></td><td height="0" id="div__labprintcol4" nowrap="" class="listheadertd listheadertextb uir-list-header-td"><div class="listheader">Customer<span class="listheadersort"></span><img class="uir-hover-icon" src="/images/hover/icon_hover.png?v=2019.2.0" alt="" border="0" style="vertical-align:middle;" title="This column is hoverable"></div></td><td height="0" id="div__labprintcol5" nowrap="" class="listheadertd listheadertextb uir-list-header-td"><div class="listheader">Stripe Code&nbsp;<span class="listheadersortup"></span><span class="uir-list-header-sort-padding-after" style="padding-right:10px;"></span></div></td><td height="0" id="div__labprintcol6" nowrap="" class="listheadertd listheadertextb uir-list-header-td"><div class="listheader">Event Date<span class="listheadersort"></span></div></td><td height="0" id="div__labprintcol7" nowrap="" class="listheadertd listheadertextb uir-list-header-td"><div class="listheader">Invoice<span class="listheadersort"></span><img class="uir-hover-icon" src="/images/hover/icon_hover.png?v=2019.2.0" alt="" border="0" style="vertical-align:middle;" title="This column is hoverable"></div></td><td height="0" id="div__labprintcol8" nowrap="" class="listheadertd listheadertextb uir-list-header-td"><div class="listheader">Invoice Sales Order<span class="listheadersort"></span></div></td><td height="0" id="div__labprintcol9" nowrap="" class="listheadertd listheadertextb uir-list-header-td"><div class="listheader">Invoice Terms<span class="listheadersort"></span></div></td><td height="0" id="div__labprintcol10" nowrap="" class="listheadertd listheadertextb uir-list-header-td"><div class="listheader">Event Type<span class="listheadersort"></span></div></td><td height="0" id="div__labprintcol11" nowrap="" class="listheadertd listheadertextb uir-list-header-td uir-list-header-align-rt"><div class="listheader">Balance<span class="listheadersort"></span></div></td></tr>
<tr class="uir-list-row-tr uir-list-row-even" id="row0">
<td valign="top" class="listtextctr uir-list-row-cell" nowrap="" style=""><a class="dottedlink edititem" href="/app/common/custom/custrecordentry.nl?rectype=176&amp;id=214433&amp;e=T" xpath="1">Edit</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a class="dottedlink viewitem" href="/app/common/custom/custrecordentry.nl?rectype=176&amp;id=214433">View</a></td>
<td valign="top" class="listtextrt uir-list-row-cell" style=""><a href="/app/common/custom/custrecordentry.nl?rectype=176&amp;id=214433" target="_self" class="dottedlink">214433</a></td>
<td valign="top" class="listtext uir-list-row-cell" style="">245950</td>
<td valign="top" class="listtext uir-list-row-cell" style=""><a href="/app/common/entity/custjob.nl?id=7426843" class="dottedlink uir-hoverable-anchor" style="cursor:pointer;" id="qsTarget_1237261608" onmouseover="var win = (typeof parent.getExtTooltip != 'undefined' &amp;&amp; parent.getExtTooltip) ? parent : window;  if (typeof win.getExtTooltip != 'undefined')var tip = win.getExtTooltip('qsTarget_1237261608', 'CUSTOMER', 'DEFAULT_TEMPLATE', 7426843,null);if(tip != undefined) tip.onTargetOver(event);">Salads &amp; Wraps</a></td>
<td valign="top" class="listtext uir-list-row-cell" style="">funds</td>
<td valign="top" class="listtext uir-list-row-cell" style="">11/14/2019</td>
<td valign="top" class="listtext uir-list-row-cell" style=""><a href="/app/accounting/transactions/transaction.nl?id=13881996" class="dottedlink uir-hoverable-anchor" style="cursor:pointer;" id="qsTarget_720078194" onmouseover="var win = (typeof parent.getExtTooltip != 'undefined' &amp;&amp; parent.getExtTooltip) ? parent : window;  if (typeof win.getExtTooltip != 'undefined')var tip = win.getExtTooltip('qsTarget_720078194', 'transaction', 'TRAN_TEMPLATE', 13881996,null);if(tip != undefined) tip.onTargetOver(event);">Invoice #INV10</a></td>
<td valign="top" class="listtext uir-list-row-cell" style="">Order #0073</td>
<td valign="top" class="listtext uir-list-row-cell" style="">On Shipping</td>
<td valign="top" class="listtext uir-list-row-cell" style="">The account has insufficient funds </td>
<td valign="top" class="listtextrt uir-list-row-cell" style="">476.00</td>
</tr>


<tr class="uir-list-row-tr uir-list-row-odd" id="row1">
<td valign="top" class="listtextctr uir-list-row-cell" nowrap="" style=""><a class="dottedlink edititem" href="/app/common/custom/custrecordentry.nl?rectype=176&amp;id=214502&amp;e=T">Edit</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a class="dottedlink viewitem" href="/app/common/custom/custrecordentry.nl?rectype=176&amp;id=214502">View</a></td>
<td valign="top" class="listtextrt uir-list-row-cell" style=""><a href="/app/common/custom/custrecordentry.nl?rectype=176&amp;id=214502" target="_self" class="dottedlink">214502</a></td>
<td valign="top" class="listtext uir-list-row-cell" style="">3831</td>
<td valign="top" class="listtext uir-list-row-cell" style=""><a href="/app/common/entity/custjob.nl?id=8650625" class="dottedlink uir-hoverable-anchor" style="cursor:pointer;" id="qsTarget_193242182" onmouseover="var win = (typeof parent.getExtTooltip != 'undefined' &amp;&amp; parent.getExtTooltip) ? parent : window;  if (typeof win.getExtTooltip != 'undefined')var tip = win.getExtTooltip('qsTarget_193242182', 'CUSTOMER', 'DEFAULT_TEMPLATE', 8650625,null);if(tip != undefined) tip.onTargetOver(event);">Bbq and Pizzeria </a></td>
<td valign="top" class="listtext uir-list-row-cell" style="">funds</td>
<td valign="top" class="listtext uir-list-row-cell" style="">11/14/2019</td>
<td valign="top" class="listtext uir-list-row-cell" style=""><a href="/app/accounting/transactions/transaction.nl?id=13552039" class="dottedlink uir-hoverable-anchor" style="cursor:pointer;" id="qsTarget_150766952" onmouseover="var win = (typeof parent.getExtTooltip != 'undefined' &amp;&amp; parent.getExtTooltip) ? parent : window;  if (typeof win.getExtTooltip != 'undefined')var tip = win.getExtTooltip('qsTarget_150766952', 'transaction', 'TRAN_TEMPLATE', 13552039,null);if(tip != undefined) tip.onTargetOver(event);">Invoice #INV20</a></td>
<td valign="top" class="listtext uir-list-row-cell" style="">Order #0068</td>
<td valign="top" class="listtext uir-list-row-cell" style="">ACH on Shipping</td>
<td valign="top" class="listtext uir-list-row-cell" style="">The account has insufficient funds</td>
<td valign="top" class="listtextrt uir-list-row-cell" style="">1,027.18</td>
</tr>
<tr class="noprint uir-noprint-list-end" style="visibility: hidden;"><td height="0" id="div__labcol1" nowrap="" class="listheadertdleft listheadertextb uir-list-header-td uir-list-header-align-ctr"><div class="listheader">Edit | View</div></td><td height="0" id="div__labcol2" nowrap="" class="listheadertd listheadertextb uir-list-header-td uir-list-header-align-rt"><div class="listheader">ID<span class="listheadersort"></span></div></td><td height="0" id="div__labcol3" nowrap="" class="listheadertd listheadertextb uir-list-header-td"><div class="listheader">ID2<span class="listheadersort"></span></div></td><td height="0" id="div__labcol4" nowrap="" class="listheadertd listheadertextb uir-list-header-td"><div class="listheader">Customer<span class="listheadersort"></span><img class="uir-hover-icon" src="/images/hover/icon_hover.png?v=2019.2.0" alt="" border="0" style="vertical-align:middle;" title="This column is hoverable"></div></td><td height="0" id="div__labcol5" nowrap="" class="listheadertd listheadertextb uir-list-header-td"><div class="listheader">Stripe Code&nbsp;<span class="listheadersortup"></span><span class="uir-list-header-sort-padding-after" style="padding-right:10px;"></span></div></td><td height="0" id="div__labcol6" nowrap="" class="listheadertd listheadertextb uir-list-header-td"><div class="listheader">Event Date<span class="listheadersort"></span></div></td><td height="0" id="div__labcol7" nowrap="" class="listheadertd listheadertextb uir-list-header-td"><div class="listheader">Invoice<span class="listheadersort"></span><img class="uir-hover-icon" src="/images/hover/icon_hover.png?v=2019.2.0" alt="" border="0" style="vertical-align:middle;" title="This column is hoverable"></div></td><td height="0" id="div__labcol8" nowrap="" class="listheadertd listheadertextb uir-list-header-td"><div class="listheader">Sales Order<span class="listheadersort"></span></div></td><td height="0" id="div__labcol9" ="" class="listheadertd listheadertextb uir-list-header-td"><div class="listheader">Invoice Terms<span class="listheadersort"></span></div></td><td height="0" id="div__labcol10" nowrap="" class="listheadertd listheadertextb uir-list-header-td"><div class="listheader">Event Type<span class="listheadersort"></span></div></td><td height="0" id="div__labcol11" nowrap="" class="listheadertd listheadertextb uir-list-header-td uir-list-header-align-rt"><div class="listheader">Balance<span class="listheadersort"></span></div></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: i'm not sure if i understand the question correctly do you want to click it using selenium?if yes using selenium you could find the element i.e top row with xpath : //tr[@id='row0']//a[contains(@class, 'edititem')] then click it

Comment: Hi, yes I want to click it using selenium. I would try that method but it isn't always going to be in the top row. I need it to be in the same row as the Invoice ID. But,  Thank you for taking your time to help me!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say if the you wanted to click based on the invoice id, you should know the invoice id right or at leas part of it e.g : INV10 . so you need to construct xpath around that like so

```
"//tr[ .//a[contains(text(),'INV10')]]//a[contains(@class, 'edititem')]"
```

the xpath `//tr[ .//a[contains(text(),'INV10')]]` means **looks for tr that has descendant anchor that has text containing INV10**

but if you wanted it to be dynamic let say it's always had INV + something, you could construct the string there and append as needed

```
String dummyVar = 10;
"//tr[ .//a[contains(text(),'INV"+dummyVar +"')]]//a[contains(@class, 'edititem')]"
```

Sorry i'm not familiar with phyton, but it should be understandable.

EDIT : i'm assuming the id is the INV10, but when i take a look you have id column. so if the id column is the invoice ID then you could do

```
"//tr[ .//td[contains(text(),'245950')]]//a[contains(@class, 'edititem')]"
```

just a warning, if you are able to put at least class in the id's **td** to make it more accurate for you to find it as well as more robust in case you have a coincident 2 elements found with the xpath

Answer (score 0):

It seem like you want click `Edit` based on particular `#INV` number, try the following `xpath`:

```
//tr[contains(.,"#INV10")]//td//a[text()="Edit"]
```

Try change `#INV10` to `#INV20` and see the result.